# Views issue: How to pull content from two different taxonomy vocabularies on same page

Tags: views

I have two Content types:
Article1 with **vocabulary1** with taxonomy terms: A, B, news;
Article2 with **vocabulary2** with taxonomy terms: X, Y, news.

I need to create a /news view page that displays content from both Article1 and Article2 tagged with "news".

I tried to use Filter Criteria:
Has taxonomy term - vocabulary1 -> news
OR
Has taxonomy term - vocabulary2 -> news
Nothing shows.

Please note that I set up Pathauto to publish in /news/article_title both Article1 and Article2 tagged with "news".
Maybe a contextual filter could be used to pull all content from /news/*?

Thanks in advance,
Cosmin

Comment: Revise the question and display a screenshot of your view please.

Comment: Why would you put news twice under diff vocabs in the first place?

Comment: Create a central vocab, Vocab 3 with term news. Article 1 allows to ref vocab 1 & 3 terms. Article 2 allows vocab 2 & 3 terms. Problem solved.

Comment: Dear No Sssweat, I have different vocabs for different roles. Thanks for the great idea. An easy fix that worked. Problem solved indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself and *views filter OR group* is not working.

I think you just hit on a known bug.

Follow the [discussion in this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1766338) and [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2559961) and apply the latest patches mentioned and see if you can make it work.  Make sure that you post back with your experience (did it work or not) so you can help this issue move along and eventually make it into a release.

**As a workaround** consider using 1 vocabulary (instead of 2) that holds all terms and your views filtering does not need an *OR group*.